# tr this href to load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

ihave the next code

```
 $('table tr').click(function(){
        $("#demo").load(this.href + " #demo2");
        return false;
    });
```

and the html is this

```
<body>
<table>
  <tr href="linkdemo.html">
    <td>hi</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

as I do so that the javascript recognize the link of the tr?

Answer (score 1):

Important: You need an  element with id `demo`

As tr doesn't have `href` property, You need to use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get its attribute.

```
$("#demo").load($(this).attr('href') + " #demo2");
```

However I would recommend you to use `data-*` prefixed custom attributes which can be fetched by using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

*HTML Snippet*

```
<tr data-href="linkdemo.html">
  <td>hi</td>
</tr>
```

*Script*

```
$("#demo").load($(this).data('href') + " #demo2");
```

Comment: I have a problem , the code is fine but do not load the specified label ' demo2 ' if I load all next page